# Synchronisation Contact List - Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-server, outlook, contacts

I'm working on a `Contact`-List in a `SharePoint 2016` farm. All the standard columns are connected/related do their fields in Outlook. What I'm trying to do is to sync also the `Title` field (Mr, Mrs, Prof,...).

Is there a way? How?

Answer (score 1):

The columns that can be synchronized to the Outlook are the columns from Core contact and Calendar Columns Site Columns.

Use these columns in the Contact list.

List settings -> Add from existing site columns -> Select site columns from: Core contact and Calendar Columns

Similar issue for you reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd016429-3062-4500-ab8e-97bb925b3c49/mapping-contact-fields-between-sharepoint-2010-and-outlook-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious